# Excel splashscreen warning of duplicate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a worksheet with columns A to R. I am trying to find a way to check for duplicate information in the same row from two columns (B & M). Column B is a date, Column M is a reference code. What I am trying to achieve is when there is a match a splash screen warning of the duplicate appears. I have got very close using formulas, but cannot quite work out how to get the data validation to kick in and show the splash screen.

This is what I have achieved so far.
Creating Column T, I have put the formula `= B2 & M2`
Creating Column U, I have the formula `=MAX(COUNTIF(T2:T300,IF(T2:T300<>"",T2)))`

I now get a list of numbers 0 for blank lines, 1 for unique lines, and 2 and upwards for duplicates.

Now It should be possible to get the Data Validation tool (which has the splash screen I am after) to create an error message on the data in Column U. I just haven't worked out how to get the Data Validation to work on the whole column. Should I be looking at the COUNTIF formula for this, or something different?

I know this seems a long way round the houses to achieve what I want to do, perhaps someone might now of an easier solution?

Comment: Do you want to stop the data from being entered in case it is entered or just having a message pop out that duplicates exist is enough?

Comment: The validation will trigger when the cell value is changed from within the cell. If the duplicate is made with the fomula aready being in Column U, the value will just update and no error will be thrown. However, you can then user the dropdown menu in the ribbon on the "Data Validation Button" and choose "Circle invalid data". Still no pop-up, but there will be a visual representation of the duplicates.

Comment: As far as the validation itself goes: You can apply "valid values" of whole number that is "<=1" to the entire column and that's it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for ge tting back to me. @Nitesh Halai, no I do not want to stop the data being entered as there is certain conditions where it would be allowed. I definitly DO want a message popping up stating that duplicates exist.@Rik Sportel, do I put the  code "<=1" into a column (and which column would it be?), or the data validation formula bar? And will this produce the pop up message I am ultimately trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Data Validation duplicate](https://www.dropbox.com/s/crqf642qrt4s28s/Screenshot%202017-07-01%2009.44.05.png?dl=0)

I have finally worked out how to get Data Validation to flag up duplicates on combined data in two different columns.

First I had to concentate the answers (Column T `= B2 & M2`). I didn't need columns U or V. Next, highlight Columns B AND U (highlight B, press CTRL and highlight U, if your columns are not adjacent). Go to Data Validation, choose custom, and enter the following formula `=COUNTIF($T$2:$T$300,$T2)<2`. Then the whole thing works beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the whole process can be done using a VBA code only, but this solution expands on what you have already done.

Enter the following formula in `V2`

```
=COUNTIF(U2:U3000,">"&1)
```

Then use the VBA code in the sheet where you have your data:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("B2:B3000,M2:M3000")

        If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
               Is Nothing Then

        If Range("V2").Value > 1 Then MsgBox ("Reference code with same date 
already exists")


    End If
End Sub
```

`Range("B2:B3000,M2:M3000")` refers to the range where data is entered. If there is any change in these, the macro will run.

So if the count of number greater than 1 in column U is greater than 1, you will get the message.

**Major downside: As long as the duplicate exists, it will keep on returning the message box, whenever you enter the data. The way out may be to insert a character either before or after the code. Alternatively, you can clear the content in column U for that particular row**

(More experience users can maybe review the above code. I am a beginner to VBA myself)

Screenshots:

**With duplicates:**

[image]

**Without duplicates:**

[image]

**Location of code:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. I must be doing something wrong. I put the formula `=COUNTIF(U2:U3000,">"&1)` in column V, and it only produced 1's & 0's despite there being some 2's in column U. I added the vba code to see if it would run anyway. Nothing happened. I tried changing the line `If Range("V2").Value > 1 Then MsgBox ("Reference code with same date already exists")` to `If Range("U2").Value > 1 Then MsgBox ("Reference code with same date already exists")` in case it would work on that column instead. Neither worked. Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: The `countif` is supposed to return the count of numbers greater than 1 in column U. I am assuming you still have `=MAX(COUNTIF(T2:T300,IF(T2:T300<>"",T2)))` in Column U? Also can you confirm what the value in U and V2 changes to something greater than `1` once you enter the duplicate record?

Comment: In Column U, the  `=MAX(COUNTIF(T2:T300,IF(T2:T300<>"",T2)))` code shows 0 for blank rows, 1 for unique data, and 2 and above for duplicates. The Countif code in Column V shows 0 on blank rows and 1 on all the other rows, including the ones showing 2 in column U. Hope that helps.

Comment: The `countif` should only be placed in V2. Can you check the value in `V2` when duplicates are present. It should be greater than 1. If it shows greater than 1, but not triggering the msgbox, then check that the code is placed in the sheet where your data is located. Not the module. Added screenshots in the answer for your reference.

Comment: So, So, close! I am using the formula `=COUNTIF(U2:U300,"?*")` in the data validation. Trouble is it only does it once, and only on column B, not on column M. Strange, as it should only be working on column U which combines B and M.. I know the formula is based on looking for text above, but should it make a difference if the code `=MAX(COUNTIF(T2:T300,IF(T2:T300<>"",T2)))` prodeces only numbers? On with the search for the answer.

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajh81ts6acgo10b/Screenshot%202017-06-28%2012.23.54.png?dl=0] @Nitesh Halai, your Countif code is one number behind the code in column U so the splash screen only showed up when there were 3 duplicates

Comment: That's strange. With your data only the moment I entered M7, it gave me the splash.

Comment: Can someone figure out what I am doing wrong please. attached is a screenshot [https://www.dropbox.com/s/ii7uwu4uvmjtgzr/Screenshot%202017-06-30%2022.12.14.png?dl=0] showing I have got it to show the splash screen when a duplicate is shown in column M. I cannot get it to only show duplicate warning when there is a duplicate row using both Column B AND M. I've tried to create extra columns to use for data validation, but both column T `= B2 & M2` and Column U `=MAX(COUNTIF($T$2:$T$300,IF($T$2:$T$300<>"",T2)))` will not produce any result with Data Validation.

Comment: The code I managed to get to work on Column M is `=COUNTIF($M$2:$M$300,M2)=1`. I just don't know how to tell it to only show a result when the date and duty match to a previous entry. I just seem to be going round and round in circles, searching all the forums for an answer to my conundrum!